# ¿Cómo conectar Angular a una base datos MySQL?

Tags: mysql, angular

Sí yo tengo el siguiente modulo donde se encuentra la `API` o sí existe algún `import` del algún modulo para hacer la conexión a una base de datos en `Angular` a `MySQL` o ¿cuales son los pasos para hacerlo?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'angular8-crud';    
}
```

Comment: Angular no se puede conectar a base de datos, ya que es framework cliente, lo que se conecta es node.js

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener tu web service creado previamente con un lenguaje del lado del servidor como php,js,go, etc y montado en un servidor (puede ser localhost con el servidor web que proporciona apache o levantar uno con nodejs eso depende tu lenguaje del servidor).

Es común y buena practica separar tus métodos los cuales son encargados de hacer peticiones a tu servidor en un servicio para ello debes generarlo en tu proyecto angular ng generate service nombreDeTuServicio y una vez ahi pones algo como esto:

```
public mostrarEntidad() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/entidadWS/listarEntidad', { headers: this.headers });
}
```

depende la peticion que quieras hacer en este ejemplo es un get y mi ws esta hecho con NodeJS (aqui se configura tu SGBD por ejemplo mysql pero ese es ya otro proyecto para crear tus WS)

ya en tu componente de angular resulves la peticion de la siguiente manera (con un subscribe):

```
public listarEntidad(){
    this.API.mostrarEntidad().subscribe(
        (success:any)=>{
            console.log(success);//el success contiene tu respuesta
        },
        (error)=>{
            console.log("algo ocurrio: ",error)
        }
   );
}
```

API aqui proviene de tu servicio es una simple instancia de la clase tu import de tu servicio.

Espero haberte ayudado, en resumen, debes crear un WS y después usarlo en angular; el WS los haces con tu SGBD preferido como mySQL por ejemplo y para conectar usas un lenguajes del lado del servidor como PHP por ejemplo.